# OTA Enrollment: MDM and SCEP

Tags: iphone, ios, mdm, ota

**Three phases in OTA**

Phase1: Collect required information via a simple initial configuration profile.

Phase2: Return a configuration profile with SCEP payload configured

Phase3: Return a configuration profile with MDM payload

**I have 2 questions:**

1. Do scep and mdm need to be on same domain?
2. How do we get control back from scep server to execute phase3? Do we need to configure scep to redirect once the cert is delivered?

Answer (score 4):

1. Your SCEP can easily be a server on another domain. I'm running a setup where my device enrolled through my local MDM server, but received the identity certificate from a SCEP server on another server with a different domain (actually located in another country).
2. After the device has successfully received a certificate from your SCEP server it will automatically contact your MDM server again to complete the enrollment. In my own case I found it necessary to package the MDM payload with another SCEP payload since the MDM payload has the mandatory IdentityCertificateUUID key.

I'm actually trying to avoid sending a second SCEP payload, and while looking for an answer I stumbled upon your questions. I hope my answers help you a bit further.

Have you read Apple's [iPhone OTA Configuration document](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/iPhoneOTAConfiguration/iPhoneOTAConfiguration.pdf)? It was an invaluable help for me during the implementation, and there is furthermore a link to other resources from this document.

Comment: Hey Thomas, any chance you open sourced the implementation? I am looking for sample code to understand the protocols more clearly. thanks!

Comment: Hey Slartibartfast, I can't because the implementation was made for one of our customers. Have you read this one: [Schuetz - Inside Apple MDM](http://media.blackhat.com/bh-us-11/Schuetz/BH_US_11_Schuetz_InsideAppleMDM_Slides.pdf)

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I have. Was hoping to see if anyone used the profile manager code in Ruby to create an MDM server that I could reuse :) Didnt want to reinvent the wheel if you will

Comment: Great to read your answer: I'm also trying to find a way to avoid two SCEP payloads and have stumbled across this page in my travels! Did you ever figure out a way to do it with just one SCEP call? Or do you just discard the first certificate once the second one is generated?

Comment: Hey Mark, whew it's been a while since I've looked at our solution, but I do not recall succeeding using just one SCEP call, they are different as mentioned in the answer from Maksym.

Answer (score 2):

1. No, they don't, because when returning configuration profile with SCEP payload to the device, SCEP server URL is included into the payload.
2. You don't need to configure any redirects. According to iPhone OTA Configuration document mentioned in previous answer, when device completes SCEP enrollment, it sends request to the same URL as in Phase 2, but this time it signs the request with the newly obtained SCEP certificate. Server verifies request's signature and understands, that device has completed SCEP enrollment and is ready to receive configuration profile with MDM payload, so server sends it in response. To summarize, both Phase 2 and Phase 3 requests from device are sent to the same URL, but the difference is in the certificate by which request is signed:
   Phase 2 - Device certificate issued by Apple
   Phase 3 - SCEP Server issued certificate

Answer (score 1):

I did this long back , but I can tell as a overview. Remember in SCEP payload you have give the MDM server url . So once the 2nd step i.e SCEP enrollment is over, the device will get the MDM url from the payload and it will hit to the server.

Be careful what you are mentioning in SCEP configuration profiles.